# Where is the source for the statement "The last exile - the sin is hidden so the end is hidden"?

Tags: sources-mekorot, golus-exile

There is a reference somewhere that says something like:

"In the first exile, the sin was known and the end was known.  The last exile, the sin is hidden so the end is hidden."

I'm looking for this reference or anything similar to it.

Comment: I recommend you [edit] in anything at all you recall about where or when or under what circumstances you came across this. It may help others find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

בפרק קמא דיומא (יומא ט ב):

"מקדש ראשון מפני מה חרב? מפני שהיה בו שלשה דברים: עבודת גילולים, וגילוי עריות, ושפיכות דמים. עבודת גילולים, דכתיב "כי קצר המצע מהשתרע". מאי "כי קצר המצע מהשתרע"? אמר רבי שמואל בר נחמני אמר רבי יוחנן: כי קצר המצע מהשתרע עליו ב' רעים כאחד וכו'. גילוי עריות, דכתיב "יען כי גבהו בנות ציון ותלכנה נטויות גרון וכו'". שפיכות דמים, דכתיב "וגם דם נקי הרבה שפך מנשה מאוד וכו'". לפיכך הקב"ה הביא עליהם שלשה פורעניות נגד שלשה עבירות שבידם. שנאמר "לכן בגללכם ציון שדה תחרש, וירושלים לעיים תהיה, והר הבית לבמות יער". אבל מקדש שני, שאנו בקיאים בהם, שהיו עוסקים בתורה ובמצוות ובגמילות חסדים, אמאי אחרב? מפני שנאת חינם שהיה ביניהם. ללמדך ששקולה שנאת חינם נגד שלשה עבירות, נגד עבודת גילולים, גילוי עריות, [ו]שפיכות דמים. ובמקדש ראשון לא היה שנאת חינם? והכתיב "מגורי אל חרב היו בת עמי", ואמר רבי אליעזר: אלו בני אדם שאוכלים ושותין זה עם זה, ודוקרין זה את זה בחרבות שבלשונם. ההיא בנשיאי ישראל הוא דהוי. רבי יוחנן ורבי אליעזר אמרי תרווייהו: **'ראשונים שנתגלה עוונם נתגלה קיצם, אחרונים שלא נתגלה עוונם לא נתגלה קיצם'". עד כאן.**

§ It was Rabbi Yoḥanan and Rabbi Elazar who both said: In the case of the former, the people in the First Temple era, whose sin was exposed and no attempt was made to disguise their conduct, the end of their punishment was exposed, and the prophet informed them that they would return to their land in seventy years. In the case of the latter, the people in the Second Temple era, whose sin was not exposed; rather, they attempted to disguise their conduct, the end of their punishment was not exposed.

https://www.sefaria.org/Yoma.9b.12?lang=bi

Comment: See chofets chaim what sinas chinom really is. He adds moshiach cannot come while it exists. That can only  mean that people who have it cannot be alive when he comes. Because if it was destroyed because of it kol shkain it cant be built when it still is here.

Comment: Two of his examples are you hate a person (whom you may not even know well) because he is richer than you. Or more likely because for some reason which you cant understand he gets more kovod than you. This other person has done nothing to you at all but you still hate him and as I wrote you may hardly know him. Usually it is older people who are 'rodef achar hakovod'. They cannot be alive when moshiach comes.

Comment: This needs at least an English source reference to qualify as an answer